# Accuracy of GPS bearing, given two locations and their accuracies

Tags: statistics, trigonometry, error-propagation

For an Android app I need to determine the accuracy of the bearing returned by the GPS. Android supplies the following data, among others:

- The GPS position
- The accuracy of the GPS position, expressed in meters, which corresponds to $\sigma$, assuming a Gaussian distribution
- The bearing

Note that no accuracy information is supplied for the bearing. Since the only thing the GPS receiver calculates directly is the position, while bearing is inferred from two subsequent position, my approach is to take two subsequent positions and their accuracy to determine an accuracy for the bearing.

Let

- $P_0$ and $P_1$ be two subsequent positions,
- $\epsilon_0$ and $\epsilon_1$ their respective accuracies in meters,
- $\psi_1$ the bearing reported at $P_1$,
- $d$ the distance between $P_0$ and $P_1$ in meters,
- $\psi_\epsilon$ the unknown accuracy of the bearing, expressed in the same unit as the bearing (degrees or radians at your option)

We can visualize this as a line segment from $P_0$ to $P_1$ having length $d$, and circles around each point, their radii being $\epsilon_0$ and $\epsilon_1$, respectively.

As long as $\epsilon_0 + \epsilon_1 <= d$, $\psi_\epsilon$ reaches its maximum when the actual locations are located just on these circles, so that the line segment connecting them lies on the common tangent of the two circles which intersects $d$.

Together with the two line segments connecting each measured location with the (presumed) actual location, this becomes a figure of two similar rectangular triangles.

Then:

$$\epsilon_0 + \epsilon_1 = d * \sin (\psi_\epsilon)$$

and thus:

$$\psi_\epsilon = \arcsin (\frac{\epsilon_0 + \epsilon_1}{d})$$

The limit is reached when $\epsilon_0 + \epsilon_1 = d$, in which case $\psi_\epsilon$ is 90°.

As soon as $\epsilon_0 + \epsilon_1 > d$, the above formula is no longer defined. Visualizing the situation, the accuracy circles overlap, which means that the actual locations can be any pair of points that is entirely within both circles and thus any bearing is possible, hence $\psi_\epsilon = 180°$.

The issues here is the sudden "jump" from 90° to 180°; also I probably haven't paid proper attention to probability here.

Is there a better formula for calculating bearing accuracy, given two positions and their accuracy?

**EDIT:**
It's been pointed out that bearing accuracy is influenced by several factors. The one that springs to my mind is that the GPS assumes the receiver has travelled along a straight line from $P_0$ and $P_1$, which will result in errors while turning. Those need to be considered separately – for now, I just need to know how the accuracy of the bearing depends on positional accuracy, without challenging any of the assumptions made by the GPS.

Comment: Such an accuracy figure will be meaningless unless $d$ is a large multiple of $\epsilon_0 + \epsilon_1$. You should simply avoid displaying the bearing at all unless $d$ is at least, say, $5(\epsilon_0 + \epsilon_1)$.

Comment: On a typical Android device, GPS updates once a second and $\epsilon$ values around 3 m are fairly good. The $5(\epsilon_0 + \epsilon_1)$ threshold would then translate to 30 m/s, or slightly above 100 km/h. This would make acquiring valid bearing information illegal in a number of countries :-)

Comment: You don't have to rely on the two newest readings. What you can do is calculate a bearing based on the most distant reading that is consistent with more recent readings. Say a reading taken 10 seconds ago indicates a bearing of $64^\circ$, and that all the intervening readings are consistent with $64^\circ$ too according to their stated accuracy. Then you can use that 10-second-old reading to calculate the bearing and the accuracy. This is just off the top of my head -- presumably there are refinements that can be made to this scheme.

Comment: About the edit: GPS does not evaluate the velocity as the incremental ratio of the position, it is evaluated using the variations of pseudoranges. So the speed and bearing are always function of the instantaneus time, not of the time interval between two fixes.

Comment: @N74 I don't quite get the latter part: bearing should be independent of time (moving faster won't change my bearing). As I understand it, GPS is not directional, thus bearing can only be inferred through position changes (if I head straight north, then stop and turn **on the spot** until I'm facing south, the GPS won't report 180° until I start moving in that direction). Or am I missing something?

Comment: I realize this is probably a question in its own right and have therefore posted it at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183862/how-does-a-gps-device-determine-bearing.

Comment: Well I don't have a GIS se account so I'll answer here. The bearing indicate by all the GPS devices is the angle of velocity wrt the North pole. So we can say it is less accurate when you Travel slowly than when you travel fast. Anyway the velocity is not evaluated in the device measuring two positions but it is function of only one position. You can say that GPS gives you the velocity vector in the position it measures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't like this problem because the accuracy in bearing given by the GPS depends on may factors and is calculated using also doppler effect on the received signals (so is usually very accurate, as long as the speed is large enough).

Moreover, to calculate the variances on positions and bearings it is better to use tools as [Kalman filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter) (which GPSs already use).

Anyway, to give an answer following your directions I think you can use the definition of [differential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function).

Your bearing can be calculated as: $$ b=\tan^{-1}\left ( \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} \right ) $$
Its differential is: $$db=\frac{\partial b}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial b}{\partial y}dy=-\frac{\Delta y}{d^2}dx+\frac{\Delta x}{d^2}dy$$ 
and represents a linear approximation of the variation of the bearing function function as its inputs change.

If we assume $\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2$ as the variation of the inputs: $$ \psi_e = \left ( \frac{\Delta x-\Delta y}{d^2} \right ) (\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2)$$ Where $\psi_e$ is in radians. This function can assume negative values so you can just take its modulo to have always a positive error.

Anyway, if this worries you, we can use the four quadrant version of the inverse tangent: $$ b=2\tan^{-1}\left (\frac{d-\Delta x}{\Delta y} \right )$$
obtaining:$$ \psi_e = \left ( \frac{\Delta x+\Delta y - d}{d(d-\Delta x)} \right ) (\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2)$$
As $\Delta x+\Delta y \gt d$ and $\Delta x \lt d$ this equation is positively definite.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As I understand it, $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ are in the same unit as $d$ – thus, if I have latitude/longitude pairs instead of Cartesian coordinates, I'd have to calculate them as $\Delta x = d \cos (\alpha)$ and $\Delta y = d \sin (\alpha)$, correct?

Comment: To have a value for $\psi_e$ in radians all the values must be in the same units (i.e. meters), so you need also $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ in meters. For all the values I suggest you to work on the Mercatore projection, so $\Delta y=R_e \Delta lat$, $\Delta x=R_e \Delta lon \cos(lat)$  and $d=\sqrt{\Delta x^2+\Delta y^2}$ (don't use haversine, the value from it is not on the same projection as the othe two). $R_e$ is the Earth radius in meters.

Comment: Forgot to mention that Android offers an API function that will return $d$, given two lat/lon pairs. So far I am relying on that function, and if I keep doing that, I'd need to obtain $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$, given $d$ and $\psi$.

Comment: Don't use the API function for the error evaluation, Pythagoras theorem is accurate enough and gives you results coherent with the other values.

Comment: In fact, looking at the source code the API function looks a lot more complex, i.e. expensive to compute. As for the Kálmán filter – that will be the next step, using the gyroscope to predict the new state.